# Many pages get a triangle-shaped warning icon in Firefox

Tags: feature-request, ssl

Many pages get a triangle-shaped warning icon even when connected over HTTPS due to the presence of insecure content. This is annoying and probably ought to be fixed.

Are there any plans to fix this annoying message?

Comment: We're working on SSL support, but it's still some ways out.

Comment: @AnnaLear Any timeline besides 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @hichris123 Not that I know of.